# CakePHP html helper link in layout

Tags: cakephp

Cant get my head around how to do this. I'm wanting to set a "Edit your account" link in the nav of a layout (layout/default.ctp). I want to give the logged in user access to only edit there details (I'll also handle this in the controller to check its the currently logged in users). But how do I do it in the layout?

I tried this and failed:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Your Account', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit', $this->Auth->users('id')));?>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it failed"? what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry I should have said - this is what I got:

Helper class AuthHelper could not be found.
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I've been over complicating things. To solve this I wrote this in the layout:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Your Account', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit'));?>
```

and passed the ID in the edit function in the users controller like this

```
$id = $this->Auth->user('id');
$this->User->id = $id;
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

there is no core auth helper. if thats your own you need to make it available globally in your app controller:

```
public $helpers = array('Auth');
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not been clear enough - in a controller I can use $this->Auth->users('id') as I;'m using the Auth component how can I add a link into a layout so the currently logged in user can edit their details?

Comment: you can use `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')`. but normally in this case you would not pass the id along. using the session you can make an edit action without any passed arguments.